# TexStudio "Inverse Search" issues

Tags: pdfpages, forward-inverse-search

I am using Texstudio/Texworks on Win10 platform, with the most updated MikTex. When I right click the pdf preview in both editors and want to use the inverse search function, it always points to the source code corresponding to the beginning of the next page.

However if I unable the "pdfpages" package, everything back to normal. And I tested the same doc on another laptop with MacOS and the 2016 version Texlive, no matter I use "pdfpages" or not everything is totally fine.

Could anyone help me with this strange issue? This is quite annoying. (PS: I contacted the author of "pdfpages" package and he confirmed that this may not be an issue related to this specific package.) I am wondering why this specific package trigger this issue. Thank you very much!

UPDATE: I find the right margin works normal for the inverse search. But the most of the area doesn't work! Once I remove the pdfpages package all areas work well!